# How to assess whether two treatments are significantly different using Cohen's d (effect size)?

Tags: statistical-significance, effect-size, cohens-d

Cohen's d is a measure of effect size calculated as:

$d = (x_1-x_2) / \sigma_{\text{pooled}}$

where $x_1$ is the mean of one group, $x_2$ is the mean of a second group, and $\sigma_{\text{pooled}}$ is the pooled standard deviation.

Let us say that one treatment has an effect size of 0.6 and another treatment has an affect size of 1.2. 
**How can I tell whether this difference is statistically significant?** I.e. does one treatment provide a significantly different outcome from another?

EDIT: The samples are not independent; each sample consists of the same 7 participants.

*I've briefly searched around but didn't find an answer for this question.*

Comment: Part of the reason effect sizes were suggested in the first place is to get away from the practice of testing every single statistic for "significance". See [Cohen (1994): The Earth is round (p < .05)](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?cluster=10018019703886757098&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)

Comment: 7 people in the first group and 7 people in the second group or 7 people altogether?