# Statistical comparison of 2 dependent cohen's ds

Tags: statistical-significance, effect-size, cohens-d

How would I statistically test the significane of the difference between two Cohen's d derived from different tests within the same sample?

Specifically, in my neuroimaging data metabolism in brain region A is reduced by 10% (with d=0.8) in a patient group compared to a control group, and metabolism in region B is reduced by 15% (with d=1.2). Both findings are highly significant.
How would I test if the effect in region B is significantly bigger than in region A.

A similar problem has been solved for effects sizes derived from independent samples in the context of meta-analyses:
[Statistical comparison of 2 independent Cohen's ds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77269/statistical-comparison-of-2-independent-cohens-ds)
but I'm not sure how this would change for effect sizes corresponding to different tests within the same sample.

By searching the archives I have found a similar question, but it hasn't been answered:
[How to assess whether two treatments are significantly different using Cohen's d (effect size)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24976/how-to-assess-whether-two-treatments-are-significantly-different-using-cohens-d?rq=1)